# About calling in android phone

Tags: android, phone-call

I want make simple call app.

**I use this code.**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:13643569345"));
startActivity(intent);
```

It does work well, but I don't want to use `startActivity`. it changes activity which system default call activity.

How can I call without using `startActivity()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I call but don't use startActivity().

You can't. There is no means to initiate a phone call except via `startActivity()`, except via custom firmware.